# How can i use depth data in cad_60

Tags: kinect, depth, cad, color-depth

i want to get distance from depth image .i have 3D position and i convert this point to 2D.know i read this coordinate data from RGB and depth image .
iin this picture  i mark 5 point and see this point data from depth image.

why this coordinate data is not correct ?

or why this data is 0 ?

how can i get real data from depth image ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The data returned by Kinect has 0 values at pixels it fails to get the depth measurement. This can happen due to several reasons but especially happens at reflective surfaces or glass etc. 
Also, the values around the edges are more error prone, so there are more 0 values around the edges than the center of the image.

So, (a) and (d) can be zero, but if you check the nearby pixels there will be depth values. (e) is a bad measurement, as it has a large value, whereas it is closer than rest of the points.

Before acquiring data, maybe you can try some hole filling technique such as [Depth Normalization](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47830-kinect-depth-normalization) on your data, to remove most of the zero values.